# Chromium local override, connection to file breaks

Tags: ubuntu, chromium, devtools

System: Xubuntu (Ubuntu 23.04) Editor: Sublime Text 3

For example, if a CSS file is open and connected (synchronously) in the developer tool, and then that file is changed to ST3, and then the page is reloaded, the connection to the file will be lost. Other files remain connected. The connection will be reestablished when the developer tools are closed and reopened. Just reloading the page is not enough. This is not good in practice. I'm just guessing it's some kind of rights issue, because that's often the case with Ubuntu, but I don't know. Where is the problem?

If you don't know, can you please tell me if this is the case for you too, even if you don't use ST3?